# logic for implementing Calorie counter functionality to a JavaScript app

Tags: javascript

I have created a dynamic app related to fitness trainer using JavaScript technology. This app automatically run according to time sets for the specific exercise.

Now I have one doubt, actually now I have to automatically calculate the users `calorie burn` during performing the exercise.
What logic do I have to implement for this?
I am already calculating the users time spent, how many reps, sets. A user is taking while performing this workout.

I need just a programming logic for this? On what basis I will calculate users `calorie burn`?

Comment: Calorie calculation has the same logic, but just need the different set of parameters involved. Basically BMI. Check out : http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/calorie-calculator.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone burns calories at different rates depending on a host of factors, including the person's age, height, weight, the specific exercise they're doing, etc. It's impossible to truly measure calories burned unless you get physiological measures, which I doubt you'll be able to do with an app. There are, however, models out there that give you crude estimates based on the exerciser's characteristics and activity. You'll have to find the regression equations in some research paper or something.

Here's a citation for a paper:

Ainsworth B.E., 2002, January, "The Compendium of Physical Activities Tracking Guide," Prevention Research Center, Norman J. Arnold School of Public Health, Univ of SC.

Here's a website with some explicit formulas, but you need heart rate information:

http://fitnowtraining.com/2012/01/formula-for-calories-burned/